# Magento 2 get database prefix on install data

Tags: magento2, database, install-script, prefix

How to get database table prefix on install data? It is showing "table or view not found".

```
<?php

namespace ...;


use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();


            $setup->getConnection()->query("INSERT INTO `sales_order_status`(`status`, `label`) VALUES ('test','Test')");



        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

It is giving error 'table or view not found'

Comment: How are you trying to get the table prefix? Please add some more info in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the table name with prefix (if, any) like :

`$setup->getTable('sales_order_status');`

and use it in InstallData.php like below :

```
namespace ...;


use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    $tableName = $setup->getTable('sales_order_status');

    $setup->getConnection()->query('INSERT INTO `'.$tableName.'` (`status`, `label`) VALUES ('test','Test')');
    $setup->endSetup();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get table prefix using `\Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig`.

First ,you have to inject the getTablePrefix `\Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig`: on `__construct()` function then using this injection you can  get prefix.

```
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Config\ConfigOptionsListConstants;

class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig
     */
    protected $deploymentConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig  $deploymentConfig
    ) {

        $this->deploymentConfig = $deploymentConfig;
    }
    public function getTablePrefix()
    {
        return $this->deploymentConfig->get(
                ConfigOptionsListConstants::CONFIG_PATH_DB_PREFIX
            );
    }
```

Comment: That is not working, I have created the method and called it to get the prefix but still no change, the database is not getting updated .

Comment: What is your issue

Comment: Please explain property what you have issue  with installer

Comment: Your question was table prefix

Comment: I am trying to add column to table 'sales_order' but it is giving error when I am trying to call "getTableName()" without database prefix, it is giving error 'table or view not found'

Comment: When I call $installer->getConnection()->addColumn( $installer->getTable('prefix_table_name')) it is working fine. But when I call   "$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_shipment_item'))" it is giving error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84475/discussion-between-akshay-billore-and-amit-bera).

Comment: Please  share your code at post

Comment: I just noticed that install schema is working fine I am having problem in 'install-data.php'